# Image won't tile vertically but does tile horizontally in Android

Tags: java, android, drawable, tiles

I'm trying to get an image to tile vertically in Android. This is what I'm using:

```
BitmapDrawable tiledImage = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap);
tiledImage.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
tiledImage.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
ImageView Item = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
Item.setBackgroundDrawable(tiledImage);
```

It works if I repeat it X and Y, but if I try to repeat it only Y (vertically) it fails to load the image. If I load it only X (horizontally) it loads just fine! Anyone got any ideas?

I also tried using `tiledImage.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);` and it still didn't work.